# JQuery is not defined in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error in my console 'JQuery is not defined'.

**Gemfile**

```
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I have ran bundle install. What else should I check?

Comment: View your Rails app in your browser and "View Source" (usually Ctrl + Shift + U). Do you see jQuery in there anywhere? Anything look weird?

Comment: hope your application.html.erb has application.js included...Can you again check for jquery in console tab of browser that its loaded...?

Comment: The source looks normal, the term jquery isn't in the source. Page also cotains <script src=.. for the single rails js file. And the rails js file appears to contains the jquery.js code

Comment: I'd first look at this question and its accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'JQuery' in your code, try 'jQuery' or '$' instead of 'JQuery'.